# How to do if statements inside main method in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and am trying to solve a fairly simple problem on hte surface but has proven to be really difficult. I have this program where I want to have a target sum for example 10 and then given an array I want to find the pairs in that array that add to the target sum. Heres what I have:

```
findPairs :: [Int] -> [Int] -> ([[Int]], Int )
findPairs x y = do
  if x + y == 10
    then 
        let thePairs = zip x y


main = do
  a <- [1, 8, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 4]
  b <- [1, 8, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 4]
  findPairs a b
```

I keep getting the same error: `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)`. So given the array [1, 8, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 4], if my target sum is 10 for example, my program will return `[(1,9),(8,2),(5,5),(7,3),(6,4)]`. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you're missing an `else` on that first `if`, your `let` is also invalid as it is not within a `do` block. You probably meant to add a `do` after `then`.

Comment: Do I have to have an else statement? Would if I don't need one

Comment: Haskell does not have `if/else` statements as you may be used to in other languages. `if-then-else` in Haskell is an expression. An expression must have a singular type, hence both branches must yield a value and both values must be of the same type. If this wasn't the case, you'd be lying about `findPairs` returning `([[Int]], Int)`. As when you omit the `else`, you omit the return value.

Comment: Also note that after the `then` and `else` a new expression is begun. If you want this expression to be a `do` block, you must start the do block yourself by writing `do` and then the block of code. The `do` outside does not take syntactic effect inside the branches

Comment: There are other problems here too. `x` and `y` in your function are lists. Why are you using `+` (addition) on lists? That doesn't make sense. I suggest going through a Haskell beginner tutorial. I'd recommend [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/introduction)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to use `do` inside `findPairs`. As a beginner, I would advise not to use `do` for anything other than IO actions (such as `main`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `findPairs` function is to be able to return `[(1,9),(8,2),(5,5),(7,3),(6,4)]`, its return type must be `[(Int,Int)]` and not `([[Int]], Int)`.

The system does not extract items from their respective lists automatically. You have to do it manually. Besides, it is customary to note the item list as xs and the item as x for clarity.

You can write the function like this, for example:

```
findPairs :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
findPairs xs ys =
  do
    -- we are in a do construct within the list monad
    x <- xs
    y <- ys
    if (x + y == 10)  then  [(x,y)]  else  []
```

In a list monadic context, function `return` just wraps 42 into [42], so you do not necessarily need to use return every time.

Sample main program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- we are in a do construct within the IO monad
  let as    = [1, 8, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 4]
  let bs    = [1, 8, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 4]
  let pairs = findPairs as bs
  let msg   = "pairs = "  ++  (show pairs)
  putStrLn msg
```

**Program output:**

```
pairs = [(1,9),(8,2),(5,5),(5,5),(2,8),(5,5),(5,5),(6,4),(7,3),(3,7),(9,1),(4,6)]
```

Comment: Note that your `do` block in `findPairs` is equivalent to the following list comprehension, which I personally find preferable and is certainly easier for a beginner to understand: `findPair xs ys = [(x, y) | x <- xs, y <- ys, x + y == 10]`

Comment: @RobinZigmond - Yes you're right. I was just trying to salvage as much as possible from the OP's original code.

Comment: Thank you! Its just confusing trying to do this in haskell at first because there are so many things i dont know yet. Like for this problem in a language like java id just use nested loops to do this pretty simple but haskell is completely different as loops arent even a thing. or if statements. Are there any resources you would recommend to solve a problem like this?

Comment: @AndrewViera In fact, loops still exist, just under a different shape. The most popular resource for Haskell beginners seems to be [LearnYouAHaskell](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/), both the web-based tutorial and [the paper book by Miran Lipovaca](https://www.oreilly.com/pub/au/5027). I also came from an imperative programming background, C/C++/Fortran, and I have found the [book by Graham Huttton](https://www.abebooks.com/9781316626221/Programming-Haskell-Hutton-Graham-1316626229/plp) very useful. Hope that helps !